# Saving a compressed string using Node.js

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, zlib

Right now, I'm compressing some data and saving it to a file in PHP using `gzcompress`. Here is my PHP code. I save this compressed string to a file and then open it from iOS using zlib.

```
$compressed_text = gzcompress($text, 9);
```

I'm trying to do the same thing in Javascript with Node.js but I can't get it to work. Here is what I tried to do in Javascript.

```
var input = new Buffer(text);
zlib.deflate(input, function(error, output) {
   var compressed_text = output.toString('ascii');
});
```

It doesn't work to decompress this data from iOS using Node.js. It works fine with PHP but I can't get it to work in Node.js. Should I be using a different method instead of `deflate`?

Comment: My best guess would be that this is an encoding issue. If I just run `zlib.deflateSync(input).toString()` (String encoding defaults to `utf-8`) the output looks identical to that of PHP. So I'd try that or change the encoding on the iOS side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

zlib output is binary, so you need some way of preserving the bytes as-is. In node, the easiest way is to just keep it as a `Buffer`. Since you mentioned saving this to a file, you could just do

```
fs.writeFile(path, output, (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Wrote data to disk');
});
```